# Can layout render(s) be used for FileName(s)?

Tags: nlog

Can layout render(s) (processname to be exact) be used for FileName(s)?

Note,

the `internalLogFile` (and INTERNAL.log value)

and

```
fileName="${processname}.NLog.${shortdate}.PeanutButter.log"
```

values below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XSD manual extracted from package NLog.Schema: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Schema-->
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="NLog NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogFile="${processname}.NLog.INTERNAL.log"
      internalLogLevel="Trace" >

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="target1" fileName="${processname}.NLog.${shortdate}.PeanutButter.log"
            layout="${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${environment-user:userName=true:domain=true}|****|${message} ${exception:format=toString,Data}|${all-event-properties}" />
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="target2"
            layout="${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=toString,Data}|${all-event-properties}" />
  </targets>




  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="target1,target2" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

With the above, I'm getting a file created:

> ${processname}.NLog.INTERNAL.log

(literally, that is the filename)

and no files at all named:

> *PeanutButter.log

where * is a wild card search.

Imported packages below.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.6.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.6.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can layout render(s) (processname to be exact) be used for FileName(s)?

### Filetarget

Yes, it's fully supported for the file target.

See this simple example from the [Filetarget docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target):

> ### Per-level log files
>
> Single File target can be used to write to multiple files at once. 
>   The following configuration will cause log entries for each log level
>   to be written to a separate file, so you will get:
>
> - Trace.log
> - Debug.log
> - Info.log
> - Warn.log
> - Error.log
> - Fatal.log
>
> ```
>  <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
>          layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}" 
>          fileName="${basedir}/${level}.log" />
> ```

#### Internal logger

> ${processname}.NLog.INTERNAL.log
>
> (literally, that is the filename)

It's not supported for the internal logger filename!

From the [Internalloger docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging)

> #### internalLogFile
>
> Note: only a few layouts are supported, as the internal log needs to be as stable as possible.
>
> - NLog 4.6+: Supported renderers (without options): `${currentdir}`, `${basedir}`, `${tempdir}`
> - NLog 4.6+: Environment Variables are also supported: e.g. `%appdata%`

If the internal logger would fail because of (complicated) layout renderers, where should it log that then? ;)

Comment: Ok, once I fixed the internalLogFile value, everything started working.  D'oh-check!  Thanks.